# What does +1 Ascension mean on Quick Ascension?

Tags: clicker-heroes

In Clicker Heroes, the Shop allows a player to buy *Quick Ascension* for 50 rubies. The button for this option says *X Souls, +1 Ascension*. What does *+1 Ascension* mean?

The popup help text does not give any further information on this. As the primary focus of this shop option is granting of immediate souls, does the *+1 Ascension* refer to a bonus soul when the player uses the normal ascension? Does it refer to an immediate bonus, or does this refer to something else, such as increasing the total number of times a player can use the normal ascension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add more clarity.

You don't actually ascend, you just receive the **designated ammount of hero souls** *(It is based on your maximum level achieved and can be increased by the ancient Solomon)* **and +1 on the ascension counter**.

**You don't receive the hero souls that are on the "Ascend for +XXX".** For that you really need to ascend using Amenhotep.

Answer (score 4):

The "+1 Ascension" quite literally just means it will increase your Ascension counter by one.

Comment: I initially thought it would _ascend you_, as in _making all the hero souls from the current run available for use_. But it just increments your counter. The only thing I can see that this would affect is the achievements or (if you have never ascended) may unlock some other stuff that is only available after ascending once.

Answer (score 1):

You have to start over and over again. The Ascension is this restart. You will loose all your heroes and start again. You will be rewarded with your hero souls and all your guilded heros will stay at you.

This shop option is useful later. It will give you hero souls based on the maximum hero souls you ever had during your playtime. This means if you currently would get +10 hero souls, but you've had a ascension which gave you +20 hero souls, you would receive 20 hero souls for buying this option.

The +1 Ascension means you get those souls just like on a restart, but you don't have to rebuild everything.

Tip: I normally use this shop option if I had a good run and raised my maximum hero souls. I do the restart, so my maximum of hero souls is increased. After that I directly buy this bonus which will grant me the same hero souls again. After that I'll go on with the next run. :-)

Hopefully this will help you.